# counting the values in xml

Tags: java, xml

I am Having an XML file

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <ticket>
  <team>A</team>
  <imp>I1</imp>
</ticket>
<ticket>
  <team>A</team>
  <imp>I2</imp>
</ticket>
<ticket>
  <team>b</team>
  <imp>I2</imp>
</ticket>
<ticket>
  <team>A</team>
  <imp>I1</imp>
</ticket>
<ticket>
  <team>B</team>
  <imp>I2</imp>
</ticket>
<ticket>
  <team>c</team>
  <imp>I1</imp>
</ticket>
```

out put to like :-

```
 Team     I1  I2   I3
  A        2   1    0
  B        1    1   0
  C        1    0   0
```

Here currently I3 is not there in XML. is it Possible to take I1,I2 and I3 into Hash and check if I1 is there then to get count accorind to team and display like above.

ticket.java

```
 package com.asn.ticket;

  public class ticket {

private String team;
private String imp;

public ticket(String team, String imp) {
    super();
    this.team = team;
    this.imp = imp;
}
public String getteam() {
    return team;
}
public void setteam(String team) {
    this.team = team;
}
public String getimp() {
    return imp;
}
public void setimp(String imp) {
    this.imp = imp;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((team == null) ? 0 : team.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((imp == null) ? 0 : imp.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) 
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ticket other = (ticket) obj;
    if (team == null) {
        if (other.team != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!team.equals(other.team)) 
        return false;
    if (imp == null) {
        if (other.imp != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!imp.equals(other.imp))
        return false;
    return true;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("ticket [team=");
    builder.append(team);
    builder.append(", imp=");
    builder.append(imp);
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
} 


 }
```

ticketcounts.java

```
       package com.asn.team;



      import com.asn.team.ticket;

        public class ticketsCount {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ticket> ticketList = new ArrayList<ticket>();
    try {

      String Path = "C:\\Users";


        File fXmlFile = new File(Path+"\\tickets.xml");

       // File fXmlFile = new File(App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("C:\\Users\// \\tickets.xml").getFile());
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

                   doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList ticketNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ticket");


        for (int temp = 0; temp < ticketNodeList.getLength(); temp++) {                
            Node varNode = ticketNodeList.item(temp);                      

            if (varNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) varNode;

                NodeList teamList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("team");
                NodeList varsionList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("imp");

                Node teamNode = teamList.item(0);
                Node impNode = varsionList.item(0);

                if(teamNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && impNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element teamElement = (Element)teamNode;
                    Element impElement = (Element)impNode;
                    ticket ticket = new ticket(teamElement.getTextContent(), impElement.getTextContent());
                    ticketList.add(ticket);
                }                   
            }               
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<ticket,Integer> count = new HashMap<ticket, Integer>();
    for(ticket c: ticketList)
        if(!count.containsKey(c))
            count.put(c, Collections.frequency(ticketList, c));

    List<String> imps = getimps(count);
    List<String> teams = getteams(count);

    StringBuilder heading = new StringBuilder("ticket \t| ");
    for(String s : imps){
        heading.append(s);
        heading.append("\t| ");
    }

    System.out.println(heading);
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");


    for(String m : teams){
        System.out.println(m+"\t| "+getNumOfteams(m, imps, count));
    }

}

/**
 * @param count
 * @return
 */
private static List<String> getteams(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
    List<String> teams = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
        if(!teams.contains(ent.getKey().getteam()))
            teams.add(ent.getKey().getteam());
    return teams;
}


private static String getNumOfteams(String team, List<String> imps, Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(String v : imps){               

            for(Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
                if(team.equals(ent.getKey().getteam()) && ent.getKey().getimp().equals(v)){
                    int cnt = ent.getValue();
                    builder.append((cnt==0)?" ": cnt);
                    builder.append("\t| ");
                }
        }


    return builder.toString();
}


private static List<String> getimps(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
    List<String> imps = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
        if(!imps.contains(ent.getKey().getimp()))
            imps.add(ent.getKey().getimp());
    return imps;
}
```

}

Comment: if we are parsing xml it will show I1 and I2 only since I3 is not there. is there any way where we can display 13 also and check if I3 is there and to display its count else as 0

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. Note thet your XML is invalid though. An XML document needs a single root element.

Comment: I tried but i am not able to succeed in that :(

Comment: Then show what you have done, and explain what the problem is.

Comment: added the code..which i am trying to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't executed your code, but if I understand correctly, it works fine except you don't have any column for I3, because no ticket in the XML file has I3 as its imp. So you simply need to do as if there was I3 in the file:

```
private static List<String> getimps(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
    List<String> imps = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
        if (!imps.contains(ent.getKey().getimp())) {
            imps.add(ent.getKey().getimp());
        }
    }

    // make sure I3 is listed as imp as well:
    if (!imps.contains("I3")) {
        imps.add("I3");
    }

    return imps;
}
```

And in the getNumOfTeams() method, you shouldn't assume that at least one ticket has the current imp. So I would rewrite it as:

```
private static String getNumOfteams(String team, List<String> imps, Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String v : imps){               
        Integer cnt = count.get(new ticket(team, v));
        if (cnt == null) {
            cnt = 0;
        }
        builder.append(cnt + "\t");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Side note: you should really learn and apply naming conventions. Don't abuse abbreviations. Name your getters and setters getTeam() and setTeam() rather than getteam() and setteam(), classes start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: yes sure i will correct the mistakes i have done. If you use above change i am able to display 0 inder I3 but it is displaying 1 under bith I1 and I2.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the code. Should be fixed now, and be more efficient since it avoids looping on the entries of the map for no reason.

Comment: thanks it worked after changing Integer count = count.get(new ticket(team, v));
        if (cnt == null) {
            cnt = 0;
        }
        builder.append(cnt + "\t");

Comment: for me final step left .. need to display this output in browser

Comment: is there any technique where we can display this out put in browser or new window as tabular format

Comment: Instead of generating text, you should generate a List<Row>, where each Row would have a team, and a list of values. You would then generate a HTML table by iterating on the rows and in each row, by iterating on the values.

Comment: instead of List<String> you suggest List<Row> am i right

Comment: An HTML table is made of rows, each row containing columns. Your code should thus produce a list of Row objects(one for each team), and each row should have a team name (for the first column), and a list of imps (for the next 3 columns). Once you have such a list of rows, creating an HTML table becomes trivial.

Comment: one suggestion needed.. instead ot displaying into browser.. is it possible to make this as an applet..

Comment: Everything is possible. But everybody hates applets.

Comment: so can you suggest me which is best approach to display this out put?? please

Comment: I already suggested it. Use an HTML table. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i will implement this as per you suggestion.. if i get stuck any where will reach experts like you.. thanks again